# Error freeing char ***

Tags: c, arrays, char, malloc, free

This is the code:

I do know what is the problem, I tried for hours to fix it, but was not successful

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void input(char ***array1,int * sizeWords,int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        char word[81] = "";
        char descrip[201] = "";
        int numAgdarot = 0;
        //how mach agdarot
        printf("how mach of agdarrot you want? ");
        scanf("%d", &numAgdarot);
        //save the count of agdarot
        sizeWords[i] = numAgdarot;

        do
        {
            printf("enter word number %d: ", i);
            _flushall();
            gets(word);
        } while (textSpace(word) == False);

        (array1)[i] = (char**)malloc(numAgdarot + 1 * sizeof(char*)); //set the num and agdarot

        //save the word
        (array1)[i][0] = (char*)malloc(strlen(word) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(array1[i][0], word);
        //save the agdarot
        for (int j = 1; j <= numAgdarot; j++)
        {
            printf("enter descrip number %d: ", i);
            _flushall();
            gets(descrip);
            (array1)[i][j] = (char*)malloc(strlen(descrip) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(array1[i][j], descrip);
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    int *sizeWords = NULL;
    int size = 0;
    char *x=NULL;// = "jk";

    char *** array1  = NULL;

    printf("enter number of word: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    array1 = (char***)malloc(size * sizeof(char**));
    sizeWords = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    //x = temp(x,sizeWords);

    //input the word and agdarot
    input(array1, sizeWords, size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeWords[i] + 1; j++)
        {
            free(array1[i][j]);
        }
        free(array1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get a "HEAP CORRUPTION DELETED" error after Normal block. Why?
If i used a debugger I see the `char *` but i can not do a free..

Comment: please repost your code.

Comment: I have to say: The question is very nice formatted! Really

Comment: Please edit your question, when you doo there will be a toolbar with a question-mark on the right-hand side. Press that to get help about how to format the text in your question, including how to make code, well, code-formatted.

Comment: it's still unreadable, wow....

Comment: Ok, it's better now, this is the `char ***` again, someone should do somthing about it.

Comment: Fifth line from the bottom; change `free(array1);` to `free(array1[i]);`

Comment: [Do not cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858?s=2|3.3985#605858).

Answer (score 3):

Doing

```
malloc(strlen(word) * sizeof(char));
```

is almost *always* wrong. Remember that strings also contains an extra character that is not reported by the `strlen` function, the terminator character `'\0'`. That means your next call to `strcpy` will write *beyond* the end of the allocated memory.

What you should do is allocate memory for that extra terminator character as well:

```
array1[i][0] = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
```

[Note that I changed the code, first because the parentheses around `array` are not needed, secondly because you [in C one should not cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), and third because `sizeof(char)` is specified to *always* be `1`.]

Remember to change on all other places where you use `strlen` in a call to `malloc`.

Comment: The multiple frees of `array1`, noted in the comments, are still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

These allocations are too small:

```
(array1)[i][0] = (char*)malloc(strlen(word) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(array1[i][0], word);

// ...    
(array1)[i][j] = (char*)malloc(strlen(descrip) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(array1[i][j], descrip);
```

You need an extra character for the terminating `\0`. `strcpy()` is writing into unallocated space.

Save yourself some trouble and:

```
(array1)[i][0] = strdup(word);

// ...    
(array1)[i][j] = strdup(descrip);
```

And, as pointed out in the comments,

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeWords[i] + 1; j++)
    {
        free(array1[i][j]);
    }
    free(array1);
}
```

should become:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeWords[i] + 1; j++)
    {
        free(array1[i][j]);
    }

    free(array1[i]);
}

free(array1);
```